# How to select next word after certain phrase? - Redshift SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Suppose I have a field with text that resembles:

```
{random text here} ABC DEF {my_variable_length_keyword} {random text here}
```

What's the simplest way to select `{my_variable_length_keyword}`?

I've tried something like:

```
select
substring(my_field, charindex('ABC DEF', my_field) + len('ABC DEF'),
        len(my_field) - (charindex('ABC DEF', my_field) + len('ABC DEF')))
from my_table
```

Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT trim('ABC DEF ' FROM regexp_substr(my_field, 'ABC DEF ([^ ]+)'))
FROM my_table
```

Comment: That's it. So Redshift supports `regexp_substr` and not `substring ... from`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `substring` with a regular expression.

```sql
select substring(my_field from 'ABC DEF ([a-zA-Z]+)') from my_table;
```

Here is an illustration.

```sql
select substring
(
  '{random text here} ABC DEF MyVarLenKwd {random text here}' 
  from 'ABC DEF ([a-zA-Z]+)'
);

-- Result: MyVarLenKwd
```

Comment: Getting an error saying `ERROR: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.`

Comment: I see. It works well on Postgresql but Redshift is not fully Postgresql compatible.

Comment: It might be because some of the `MyVarLenKwd` contains non-alphabetic characters (e.g. `.`). Could you possibly modify the code to account for that too? I'm not too familiar with regex yet

Comment: I do not think that this is the reason. If it were then there would have been no errors and the `substring` expression would return a wrong result, i.e. to the first non-alphabetic character. Anyway, in order to include `.` the regex shall be `ABC DEF ([a-zA-Z\.]+)`